# I am struggling to calculate median stepwise distance in a data set using R

Tags: r

I am working to calculate the median distance over time for where we catch crayfish in traps. We have ponds with traps over multiple years and know the # of traps we set and the # of the trap an individual is caught in.

This dataframe is set up to be an example of what I am trying to do.

```
# Create vectors for each column
Pond <- c("Aubrees", "Aubrees", "Kohls", "Kohls")
Year <- c(2019, 2020, 2019, 2020)
TrapNumbers <- list(c(1, 9, 2, 3, 6), c(3, 4, 9, 2, 5), c(3, 4, 9, 2), c(1, 9, 2, 3))
NumberofTraps <- c(10, 10, 12, 12)

# Initialize an empty vector to store all TrapCaught values
TrapCaught <- numeric()

# Iterate over the lists of TrapNumbers to combine them into one vector
for (trap_list in TrapNumbers) {
  TrapCaught <- c(TrapCaught, trap_list)
}

# Create the dataframe
DF <- data.frame(Pond = rep(Pond, sapply(TrapNumbers, length)),
                 Year = rep(Year, sapply(TrapNumbers, length)),
                 NumberofTraps = rep(NumberofTraps, sapply(TrapNumbers, length)),
                 TrapCaught = TrapCaught)
```

The NumberofTraps column tells me how many traps are set in the pond in a circular arrangement around the shoreline. So the distance between a 1 and 9 in a pond with 10 traps is 2 and not 8. I also do not want to calculate the distance between a point and itself. When I do this manually for these I find these values for the distances and the median value for a pond and year.

Aubrees 2019
median distances: 2, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3
median = 3

Aubrees 2020
median distances: 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3
median = 2.5

Kohls 2019
median distances: 1, 6, 1, 5, 2, 5
median = 3.5

Kohls 2020
median distances: 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 1
median = 3

I have this code I was trying but I am not getting the expected values.

```
library(dplyr)

# Function to calculate pairwise distances between two vectors
pairwise_distances <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  outer(x, x, "-") %% n
}

# Calculate the median distance for each group
median_distances <- DF %>%
  group_by(Pond, Year) %>%
  summarize(median_distance = median(pairwise_distances(TrapCaught)[upper.tri(pairwise_distances(TrapCaught))]))

# Print the result
print(median_distances)
```

The values output are:
Pond: Aubrees, Aubrees, Kohls, Kohls
Year: 2019, 2020, 2019, 2020
Code Median Output: 2, 2.5, 2.5. 2.5
Expected Median Outcome: 3, 2.5, 3.5, 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pairwise_distances()` function is not computing the pairwise distances you are after.

Starting with `Pond`, `Year`, `TrapNumbers`, and `NumberofTraps`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(Pond, Year, TrapNumbers, NumberofTraps)

pairwise_distance <- function(x, end) {
  a <- abs(outer(x, x, `-`))
  b <- abs(a - end)
  pmin(a, b)[upper.tri(a)]
}

output <- df |>
  mutate(distances = map2(TrapNumbers, NumberofTraps, pairwise_distance),
         median_distance = map_dbl(distances, median))

output$distances
# [[1]]
#  [1] 2 1 3 2 4 1 5 3 4 3
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] 1 4 5 1 2 3 2 1 4 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 6 5 1 2 5
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 4 1 5 2 6 1
```

Otherwise, if you are starting with `DF` you can modify the above to create the same output with:

```r
output <- DF |>
  summarize(distances = list(pairwise_distance(TrapCaught, unique(NumberofTraps))),
            median_distance = map_dbl(distances, median), .by = c(Pond, Year))
```

**Output**

```
  Pond     Year TrapNumbers NumberofTraps distances  median_distance
  <chr>   <dbl> <list>              <dbl> <list>               <dbl>
1 Aubrees  2019 <dbl [5]>              10 <dbl [10]>             3  
2 Aubrees  2020 <dbl [5]>              10 <dbl [10]>             2.5
3 Kohls    2019 <dbl [4]>              12 <dbl [6]>              3.5
4 Kohls    2020 <dbl [4]>              12 <dbl [6]>              3
```